# using spread operator (...) in mapStateToProps causes stale value to be passed to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have code like this for my component which is a function component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (errors['update'].error || successes['update'].success) {
    setUpdateInProgress(false);
  }
}, [errors['update'].error, successes['update'].success])
```

`error` and `success` properties are independent of one another, and when either of them is true, I want to call `setUpdateInProgress`.

in `mapStateToProps` I have code like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  return {
      // other fields
      errors: {...store.prop1.errors, ...store.prop2.errors},
      successes: {...store.prop1.errors, ...store.prop2.errors};
}
```

These `errors` and `successes` objects are the props I need to send to my component in order for the `useEffect` to work. As is apparent, I want to combine properties from multiple places into one(`prop1`,`prop2`, ...).

Problem is, it's not working, and the `useEffect` is not called. To get it to work, I have to split the props like below:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  return {
      // other fields
      prop1Errors: store.prop1.errors,
      prop2Errors: store.prop2.errors,
      prop1Successes: store.prop1.successes,
      prop2Successes: store.prop2.successes
  }
```

Why would the spread operator lead to a stale value being set from the state whereas using the state value directly wouldn't?

**Edit**: For those interested, `errors` and `successes` have a structure like this:

```
errors: {
  create: {
    error: true,
    message: "Error in create"
  },
  update: {
    error: false,
    message: ""
  }
  //... same thing for other actions like fetch, etc
}

//... same thing for successes
```

As for the reducer code, it's something like this:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  if(action === "UPDATE") {
    return {...state, errors: { ...state.errors, update: { message: '', error: false }}, successes: { ...state.successes, update: { message: 'Update successful.', success: true }}}
  }
}
```

Comment: From this perspective it appears you are mixing props into state which is an anti-pattern in react. Perhaps I'm mistaken and it's just a coincidental naming convention. Why can't your reducers form the state object you want? Can you include that code?

Comment: @DrewReese If you mean `this.state`, yes, that's a mistaken name. I'll update it to `store` to mean the Redux store.

Comment: No, I was referring to the fact it seems you are storing props in state (or redux store, it's all app state). If not updated/maintained properly this has the issue of becoming stale quite easily. If you *always* consume props ***from*** `props` this can't possibly happen (in the consuming component that is, props can be stale in a component higher in the tree). I think the issue is is possibly your reducer, in other words, how you are forming your state object.

Comment: can you add code from your Redux store as well where prop1 and prop2 are being set ?

Comment: @PranayTripathi check edit. prop1 and prop2 have separate reducers with code like given.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the `update` property in both of your error reducers, so the latter ends up overwriting the first as @Mihai's answer suggests?

Comment: @NemanjaLazarevic Yes, I'm sure. The code given here is simplified code; in reality there are multiple identifiers in the reducers e.g. `updateA`, `updateB`, etc. There are no name clashes because `A`, `B`,... are changing according to the reducer names.

Comment: @DrewReese I have posted my reducer code. There are a lot of such similar action handlers in various reducers, but mostly a duplicate of this. Do you see any problems here that I could check?

Comment: Does `console.log(props.errors)` inside your functional component shows the changes after reducer updates?

Comment: When you are doing the shallow merge that you are overwriting values, for example, the values of `...store.prop1.errors` are overwritten in the new object literal when you `...store.prop2.errors`. Perhaps if you shared a more [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) state shape and reducer example we could better help you, or you can follow @Mihai's solution and do a better/smarter deep merging of your separate state properties.

Answer (score 1):

Spread properties in object initializers copy their own enumerable properties from a provided object onto the newly created object. If the spread property already exists in the newly created object, it will be automatically replaced.

In other words, if you have 2 objects: `const foo = {a: 1}` and `const bar = {a: 2, b: 1}`. The result of `{...foo, ...bar}` would be `{a: 2, b: 1}`. So you can see that the assigned `a` property was the one from the last spread object.

This is exactly your case. You must consider deep merging since you have a multi-dimensional structure for errors and successes.

Based on your errors structure, I would do a function that merges the errors/successes as follows:

```
const mergeMessages = (type, ...messages) =>
{
    return messages.reduce((carry, message) => {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(message)) {
            if (!carry.hasOwnProperty(key) || value[type] === true) {
                carry[key] = value;
            }
        }

        return carry;
    }, {});
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  return {
      // other fields
      errors: mergeMessages('error', store.prop1.errors, store.prop2.errors),
      successes: mergeMessages('success', store.prop1.successes, store.prop2.successes),
  }
}
```

Comment: Properties getting replaced is not a problem for me. I have made sure that there are no properties with conflicting names; I just need to combine all into one for convenience in using in the child component.

Comment: Can you please show us the structure of `prop1.errors` and `prop2.errors`?

Comment: Could you give a short code example of how you'd do deep merging? I've tried using `Object.keys` and `Object.values` to copy properties, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please note that I updated the answer changing Object.keys to Object.entries.. my mistake